# Setting up tunnel to access compute nodes behind private LAN via front-end

Tags: front-end, parallelization

**Context**

I find the front end on macos way more convenient and I would like to keep my notebooks on my macbook. On the other hand, I have access faster multi-core linux machines behind a LAN.

Hence I would like to be able to use machines with multiple cores which are within a private LAN as remote kernels for a Mathematica front end running on a mac laptop.

The setting is the following:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Attempts**

- I know how to set up the (mac) front end on the laptop to run MathKernels on the front-end. (dark green MathLink connection)
- I know how  to set up the the (linux) front end to run MathKernels on the compute nodes. (light green MathLink connection)
- If I put my laptop within the private LAN I can run MathKernels on the compute nodes

**Question**

> How do I simply setup the extra options in this dialog box
>   [image: Mathematica graphics]
>
> so as to tunnel through to,say compute 2 from my mac laptop?

**Update**

@Szabolcs suggests [this set of updated scripts](http://www.unisoftwareplus.com/download/Tunnel.zip)

Comment: Might be useful: http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/7250/

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks. I did find this but it seems to involve mma 6 and looks a bit complicated.

Comment: Finally found it: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6226196/695132  Take a look at the comments for a newer version of the same (by 'sakra').  I don't use this myself anymore so can't give much advice ... the reason is that I found remote connections to be extremely unreliable when I was using Windows XP (freezing front end), so I gave up.  I remember others told me they couldn't reproduce the problems I saw on more modern systems, so you shouldn't give up on OS X because of this.

Comment: Thanks again. I ll try tomorrow at work!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having convinced our SysAdmin to grant me access to one compute node by [VPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network),

> I managed to connect to one compute node (b1) using the following parameters
>   in the `KernelConfiguration` submenu in the `Evaluation` menu.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that I added both to `MLOpen` and to `Launch command` the extra parameter

```
   -Linkhost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

where `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` is the IP address of the front-end through the VPN.
(which you can access via `ifconfig` on the frontend host), e.g.

```
   utun0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
   inet 10.8.0.18
```

in my case

> Then, having launched this `tunnel1` Kernel, I am able to drive another sets of 
>   three compute nodes via the following command (each of them 40 cores):

```
Needs["SubKernels`RemoteKernels`"];    
(LaunchKernels[
     RemoteMachine[#, 
      "ssh -x -f -l `3` `1` math -mathlink -linkmode Connect `4` \
-linkname '`2`' -subkernel -noinit", 40]] // Length) & /@ {"b2","b3","b4"}

 $KernelCount
```

(* 160 *)

I am now in a position to use 160 kernels instead of 4, which is pretty cool ;-)