# How to use a remote windows laptop for NetTrain?

Tags: machine-learning, kernel, remote-access, kernel-startup

I have a windows 10 laptop (with a gpu) at home and a macbook at my office, both with v11.3.

What are steps to use the windows machine remotely for training? That is, I want to launch and run kernels on the windows machine using my macbook's front-end.

I've done this with ubuntu boxes on AWS, but perhaps this is easier/harder?

Comment: You can ssh into the remote machine?

Comment: I'm doing it with remote kernel launching through ssh.

Comment: Should be doable, but lots of tricky network/firewall settings to get right... so if someone has done this before they should post a tutorial!

Comment: This may help you? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/67767/setting-up-tunnel-to-access-compute-nodes-behind-private-lan-via-front-end

Comment: This question is impossible to answer. There are too many unknown factors that depend on your network connection between home and office, firewall, visible IP addresses, dynamic DNS, etc.. Before you can even think about opening a kernel, you need to ensure that e.g. an ssh connection is working. None of which can be answered by some of us.

Comment: @halirutan Actually, I think this question could be easily answered. Just use channels or any syncing service + some kind of daemon.

Comment: @M.R. I have a different view. Let's assume my personal situation: I have a local ISP, all traffic over long-range wireless connections with several hops in between. If I wouldn't know the network, there is no way a normal user could figure out how to reach my machine from the outside. Your ISP can easily block most ports that aren't essential. Btw, I had already a good page of the answer, but I decided not to post it. Too many unknowns and this question cries for a long and unsuccessful remote debugging session trying to figure out a way to connect from his office to his home.

Comment: Additionally, I'm not on Windows 10. But if you like to post an answer, go ahead. If it works, be sure you get my upvote.

Comment: @halirutan done - let me know if you can make it better :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here's a file syncing service solution:

**Step 1:** Get a Dropbox account and make two folders in your dropbox: 'to_run/' and 'finished/'.

**Step 2:** Paste and run this in a notebook on your Windows box:

```
Options[run] = {"Print"->False};
(* runs a notebook f and saves its result *)
run[f_, opts:OptionsPattern[]] := Module[
     {nb, pdfName, doneName, tmpName, t, msg},
        tmpName = StringInsert[f, "_IN_PROGRESS",-4]; CopyFile[f, tmpName];
        doneName = StringReplace[tmpName, "_IN_PROGRESS" -> "_DONE"]; t = Now;
        nb = NotebookOpen[tmpName]; NotebookEvaluate[nb, InsertResults->True];
        NotebookSave[nb];
        If[OptionValue[opts,"Print"],
            pdfName = StringTake[doneName,;;-4]<>".pdf";
            NotebookPrint[nb, pdfName];
        ];
        NotebookClose[nb]; CopyFile[tmpName, doneName]; DeleteFile[tmpName];
        msg = StringForm["``: Evaluted `` in ``", Now, FileBaseName@f, Now-t];
        Print[msg]; ChannelSend["example", msg]; (* e.g. monitor things *)
        doneName
    ]

runner[indir_, outdir_] := Module[
    {fns = {}, done = {}, ran, to},
      Print[StringForm["Listening for files in ``", indir]];
      While[True,
        Pause[3]; done = {};
        fns = FileNames["*.nb", indir];
        Do[
            If[!MemberQ[done,f],
                Print[StringForm["Working on ``",f]];
                to = FileNameJoin[{outdir, FileNameTake[f,-1]}];
                CopyFile[f, to]; ran = run[to];
                If[FileExistsQ[to], DeleteFile[f]; DeleteFile[to]];
                AppendTo[done, f];
            ]
        ,{f, fns}]
     ]
]

runner["C:\\Users\\Dropbox\\to_run" , "C:\\Users\\Dropbox\\finished"]
```

**Step 3:** Drag a notebook you want to remotely evaluate into the 'to_run/' folder and wait for the notebook result to appear.

**Notes:**

- This is just a 5-min prototype, you should re-write this to make it robust to notebooks that crash the kernel and handle other issues like name collisions.
- Make sure both laptops have persistant internet access and a dropbox daemon running.
- You can add monitoring easily through a channel with `ChannelListener` and `ChannelSend`
- To easily save things that you need in the resulting notebook use `DumpSave`, `PersistantSymbol`, or just throw in some `Iconize` calls.

Comment: This works awesomely! I don’t know how to award the bounty I think it expired

Comment: Nice and simple. You got my vote for this.

Comment: Can you make this work for Linux? So I can train in AWS?

Comment: @user5601 Maybe halirutan can think of something, but I'm not sure of Dropbox works on linux shell.